# How to put NO LOCK for stored procedure T-SQL for all tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want that my tables will not be locked. Is it possible to set NO LOCK for all tables in the stored procedure. What is the best way if I have a lot of tables like this:

```
select * from t1
join t2 ..
join t3 .. with (nolock)

select * from t4
join t4 ..
join t5 etc...
 with (nolock)
```

Comment: Why you need NOLOCK ? NOLOCK <> without locks / zero locks. Even with NOLOCK, SQL Server will need/take a `Sch-S`(tability) lock. If you have performance problems (example: blocked processes, deadlocks) then the solution is to optimize (ex. indexing, query rewriting) T-SQL source code. Most of the time, using NOLOCK means avoiding /  hiding the root cause of the problem(s).

Comment: I had a manager (who thought he was an architect) FORCE the team to put nolock on everything....then wondered why some data-reads came back as looking incomplete.  Dirty-reads = Dirty-bird.  Work to optimize your database, not put in herky-jerky things.  With DMV queries, its much easier (since the dark ages of SqlServer 2000) : http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/five-dmv-queries-that-will-make-you-a-superhero-in-2011/

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this as long you don't have serious reasons to do it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can set this at the query level:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

Like NOLOCK, this allows for dirty reads.

Comment: Is this just for the scope of the stored procedure if it is used in stored procedure?

Comment: @qub1n yep,  just the scope of the query or stored procedure.

Comment: @PhilSandler - Does this statement make sure that there is no locking or locking will be ignored and this will avoid deadlocks or blockings? I know its been 2 years but would appreciate if you can answer.

Answer (score 1):

If dirty reads are a problem you may look into using 'Isolation level Snapshot': this creates a regular snapschot of your database and uses that for calculation.
Downside is that this copy requires extra memory.

Comment: It doesn't create a snapshot of the database, it uses row versioning